# Implement Parallel::MPI in perl script

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, mpi

I have a code that I would like to parallelize over 8 nodes, 8 processors per node.

I don't have a clue how to properly implement `Parallel::MPI::Simple`

Here's the basic code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# initialize parallelizing here 
foreach(keys %hash1){
    #fork job

    foreach my $fh (@files) {
        #get data
        open OUT, ">>".$ofh;
        print OUT $data,"\n";
        close OUT;
    }

    # end fork
}
# end script
```

I would then run it like this I assume

```
#PBS -l nodes=8:ppn=8
mpirun -n 64 perl parallelizing.pl
```

I'm confused over the documentation. **I do not need the nodes to talk to each other**. Just execute a the same command in different files over multiple nodes. Then open, print, and close.

thanks so much!

Comment: If you don't need the different instances of your script to communicate with each other, you don't need MPI. You do need to consider a couple of things, though: 1) How will each instance know which files it's responsible for processing? 2) If different processes will be writing to the same file(s) simultaneously, the output can get interwoven; often it's better to accumulate the output for each process separately and combine them all at the end.

Comment: 1) Each instance knows the file because it iterates the file handle. 2) You're talking about millions of lines that I cannot save into a data structure but need to write out.

Comment: 1) I don't know what you mean by "iterates the file handle," but I assume you're talking about your `@files` array. If `@files` contains A, B, C, D, E, and F, you need a way to indicate that the processes on node 1 should work on files A, B, and C, while the processes on node 2 should work on files D, E, and F. A simple way to do this might be based on the hostname, but you could also use MPI. 2) I never said anything about saving to a data structure. You can accumulate the output in a separate file per process, and then merge the files at the end. Unleslikes interleavedyou output ;)